# Trying to play sound from a URL Java

Tags: java, url, audio

I am having troubles with playing a sound from a certain URL.

Here is my current code,

```
    public static void aplay(String url) throws
    MalformedURLException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, 
    IOException, LineUnavailableException {

      Clip c = AudioSystem.getClip();
      AudioInputStream a = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new URL(url));
      Clip c = AudioSystem.getClip();
      c.open(a);
      c.start();
}
```

Also, I have this method in my 'main' method. I put https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=en&q=Hi%20There as the 'url' and it would not work, and it would respond with a 403 (Server returned HTTP response code: 403). I am just wondering if I could fix this.

Thanks,
  Dan

Comment: 403 means Forbidden.  Generally, unless you have some level of access, this won't be fixed easily.

Comment: @rfornal is there any alternative to the google speech link?

Comment: There are a few alternatives ... I've used a few creating training videos, but not programatically as you're doing here.

Answer (score 0):

The URL is a sound file from Google Translate. In order to prevent misuse of the Google services, the server performs a few heuristic checks with which it tries to tell whether it's a human or an automated service accessing the URL. That's why it replies with 403, which actually means "Forbidden".

Disclaimer: Consider why they forbid it and check their terms of usage.

Opening the URL directly in a browser like Chrome works. Retrieving the URL with a tool like wget or class URL doesn't - at least not out-of-the-box.

You need to change the `User-Agent` property of the HTTP request in order to fake a different user agent. You can do that by connecting "manually" and changing the "User-Agent" request property.

The following `WGet.java` listing demonstrates how to do so:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class WGet {
    public static void main(final String... args) throws IOException {
        for (final String arg : args) {
            wget(arg);
        }
    }
    public static void wget(final String arg) throws IOException {
        wget(new URL(arg));
    }
    public static void wget(final URL url) throws IOException {
        final URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "My Client");
        try (final InputStream in = con.getInputStream()) {
            copy(in, System.out);
        }
    }
    public static void copy(final InputStream in, final OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        final byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
        for (int bytesRead; (bytesRead = in.read(buf)) != -1; )
            out.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

`AudioSystem` can also be used with an `InputStream`. So, the following `aplay()` method should work:

```
public static void aplay(String url) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException {
    Clip c = AudioSystem.getClip();
    AudioInputStream a = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(openStream(url));
    Clip c = AudioSystem.getClip();
    c.open(a);
    c.start();
}
public static InputStream openStream(String url) throws IOException {
    final URL url = new URL(url);
    final URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "My Client");
    return con.getInputStream();
}
```

Disclaimer: I am showing you the technical solution. If you add this code to your program and use it to get sound files from Google, you may actually be violating the terms of use of Google Translate. Get legal advice regarding that before you use this code in product to get sound files from Google Translate.